# how to search date in any format in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have a search form with a dropdown selection which enables user to search by a specific column.Here's my code:

```
<form action="<?php echo site_url('admin/home/search');?>" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8"> 
    <div class="pull-left" style="margin-left:150px" >  
        <select class="form-control pull-left" name="searchby" id="searchby" >
            <option class="label">- Search by -</option>
            <option value="name">Name</option>
            <option value="address">Address</option>
            <option value="date">Date</option>
        </select> 
    </div>    
    <div class="pull-right" style="margin-left:10px">
        <div class="input-group col-sm-12">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search " name="key_key" id="key_key" required /> 
            <div class="input-group-btn">
                <button class="btn btn-md" type="submit"><span class="fa fa-search"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div> 
</form>
```

If I search by date and I input March it doesn't give any result.
Here's my MySQL statement:

```
$sql = "SELECT *,date_format(schedule,'%M %e, %Y') as datesched,date_format(schedule,'%h:%i:%s %p') as timesched FROM `event` WHERE schedule LIKE '%".$search_term."%'";

    $query = $this->db->query($sql);

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
        foreach($query->result() as $row){
            $data[] = $row;
        }
        return $data;
    }else{
        return 0;
    }
```

the datatype of `schedule` column is `timestamp`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't just use a string to search on a `datetime` field.
To do so, you *must* know in what format does the search string is framed.

If search string is in `YYYY-MM-DD` format then it matches with database date format. Then instead of `like` operator you can directly use as below:

```
WHERE date_format(schedule, '%Y-%m-%d') LIKE '%".$search_term."%'"
```

You have to fix the date input format for search string.

If JS and CSS framework you are using supports a CSS class to apply for a text field use it. You better opt for a `onChange` event for select options and change the datetime type CSS class for the search string input element. That will resolve your issue.

**Refer to**:

- [MySQL: Date and Time Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html)
- [jQueryUI: Datepicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/)

Comment: `<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
  $('#searchby').onchange({
   if($(this).value=='date'){
    $("#key_key").prop("type", "date");
   }
  });
 }
</script>` this doesn't work..

Comment: as I am working on this, I somehow got it but how can I disable datepicker when the value of `<select>` tag is not date?

Comment: use the same on change to reset the css

Comment: It work already but I have problem with it. Thanks for the idea anyway :) Take a look at this.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29314624/how-to-search-date-in-any-format-in-mysql/29314719

Answer (score 0):

1. `String` to `Date` format with `str_to_date()`
2. `SELECT STR_TO_DATE('12/15/2008', '%m/%d/%Y');`
3. same as your query with these changes

Answer (score 0):

Using `LIKE` in this case is wrong, because you can use ranges, like `BETWEEN`.

You have to firstly generate the rage you are looking for, let's say March 2014, then have:

```
$from = '2014-03-01 00:00:00';
$to   = '2014-03-31 23:59:59';
```

and use them in your query:

```
$query = "SELECT 
    *,date_format(schedule,'%M %e, %Y') as datesched,
    date_format(schedule,'%h:%i:%s %p') as timesched 
FROM `event` 
WHERE schedule BETWEEN '".$from."' AND '".$to."'";
```

you can generate a date starting from a string in multiple ways, take a look at http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-parse.php

I personally use http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php